# How do I find storage folder in android device monitor?

Tags: android

I can't find the folder containing videos and pictures on my tablet using the file explorer of `Android Device Monitor`.

The folder I'm trying to find is "Internt lager" which translates to internal storage in english:

[image: images folder]

I can expand all folders in the device monitor file explorer without finding my movie files, image files, downloaded files, etc. If I try to pull `storage/self/primary` for instance, I get an empty folder.

[image: adbms]

I know the `storage/emulated` folder is a symbolic link, but I need to find out where it points to, so that I can open my files in my app.

Comment: Try the ES File Explorer app.